# Get progress value and status of a MSI installation

Tags: delphi, installation, windows-installer

I am creating a Delphi application which will execute a msi silent installation . I want to get the progress value of the msi and get the installation status and show it on the delphi applcation

and also i want to close the msi if a button in the Delphi application is clicked.

I am using delphi application because no any installation software gives some facilities i want

Comment: And also i am searching for msi api for delphi

Comment: use `JwaMsi.pas` and friends from http://jedi-apilib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jedi-apilib/jwapi/trunk/Win32API/ ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the progress value, you must use the [`MsiSetExternalUI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370384) function which is part of the [`Windows Installer API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then parse the `INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS` string, you can read more info here [`Parsing Windows Installer Messages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa370573). the `jedi-apilib` has a translation of the headers of this api in the [`JwaMsi`](http://jedi-apilib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jedi-apilib/jwapi/trunk/Win32API/JwaMsi.pas?revision=1094&view=markup) unit.