# WPF application for MSI installation with silent mode then get progress and status message

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

I have to install MSI file in silent mode using WPF application and need to show install progress and status message. I am installing MSI using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller assembly and installation completed properly.

How could I get progress of installation and status message from above assembly? or Is there any other method to install msi with silent mode and get progress and status message to show in UI of WPF application?

```
Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);
Installer.InstallProduct(sourcePath, "Arguments");
```

I have looked into below link,

[Get progress value and status of a MSI installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184110/get-progress-value-and-status-of-a-msi-installation)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/installer-function-reference

How to make use of it in WPF application?. Is there any sample code in C# available in any link?

Please any one help on this?

Comment: [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) has a managed bootstrapper framework, [here is a tutorial](https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview). [And another one](https://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/). Another option is [WiX# (WixSharp)](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp) which also supports custom WPF UI.